# Java Web App: Code to receive UDP packets

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, udp

I recently started a dynamic web application using Java/JSP and Tomcat.
I did a bit of research, and there's no specific answer about it. I have my front-end JSPs and their handling is done on the corresponding servlets. This is nice and all, and is sort of local.

But I'd want the application to also run another Java class that loops and waits for incoming UDP packets from other external clients. I have a separate UDP receive class which works fine on its own, but I'd like this code to run in the background of the web application.

Is there any way this could be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably. But it's probably not a great idea.

Comment: But if I want to receive external packets, is there a 'good' way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to use UDP?

Comment: I like that there's no handshaking and no need for a dedicated port for each connection (multiple clients?). But I can switch to TCP if needed, either way, this would need its own class somewhere that runs in parallel or something?